# How to make Alt+Tab text bigger

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, alt-tab

I'm using Windows 10 and Alt+Tab is set as "classic". Is there a way do change the font for the name of the icons? Essentially make it bigger.

[image]

Comment: Try Start, Settings, search for Make Text Bigger, and use a a larger text scaling setting.  See if that affects your Alt Tab font size.

Comment: Yes, but I'm interested only in that text, nothing else.